# What is badge “Promoter” on MSO for

Tags: support, meta, badges

I cannot set bounties on MSO anymore.
Then, what is "Promoter" on MSO for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All sites list all badges even if you cannot earn them, and child metas are no exception. You cannot earn *Promoter* on a child meta site, but it still is listed because *all* badges are listed *everywhere*.

Stack Overflow has the Constable and Precognitive badges, for example; neither can be earned there. Several other sites have not gone through the Area51 process either, nor have they ever had pro-tem moderators, yet those badges are listed everywhere.

Also see [Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S[OFU] badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges) on Meta SE.

Comment: Pff, you're too fast. ;)

Comment: @Bart: this one was posted to MSE first, so I half expected it..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That seems Precognitive. Sure you didn't earn that badge?