# Shouldn't "precognitive" badge be marked as "retired" or "not available" somehow? Why is it there?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I have been curious about `Precognitive` badge, and after searching a little bit in Meta, I noticed that it cannot be awarded, as the site existed before the Area51 process came to being.

There is a retired badge, i.e. `Analytical` which is already awarded to certain number of people, where as for `Precognitive`, no one ever has it, for the obvious reason we all know. So, what's the point of having it in the badge list? Isn't it better to add a small metadata about it in parentheses or something saying that *this badge cannot be awarded to anyone anymore*?

*[P.S. Not sure if `badge-request` is a proper tag for this post or not.].*

Comment: @mehow Did you read the first line of my question mentioning that I posted this after searching? I could not find any similar question after searching with several keywords. Please let me know of the duplicate questions if there are any.

Comment: Did you actually read my question at all? I have read those *possible duplicates* that are **NOT** duplicates, and what I am posting here is something totally different. I'm questioning the reason behind the badge's existance and **requesting** an update on it's meta.

Comment: let me quote Martijn : **`All sites list all badges even if you cannot earn them, and child metas are no exception. You cannot earn Promoter on a child meta site, but it still is listed because all badges are listed everywhere.`**

Comment: Thank you for the information and the links, however it doesn't contain an answer to what I'm asking here. I am suggesting adding some more info on its wiki/metadata clarifying this.

Comment: @Neeku: My answer does link to [Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S\[OFU\] badges?]([Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S\[OFU\] badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71712)), which contains Jeff's motivation: *The Precognitive badge appears in the badge list on every site to announce the presence of Area 51, and its primary function.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I do understand it completely and I'm not disagreeing with it, but what I'm asking here is: "Isn't it worth adding this information to the badge meta/description?"

Comment: No, the badge descriptions are deliberately kept concise, and uniform across all sites.

Comment: OK @MartijnPieters, this is a proper explanation, although my suggestion wouldn't make it specific to one site only. Thank you for providing it anyhow, but was this explained elsewhere before?

Comment: Are we doing that thing again where we close questions as duplicates based on answers and not... questions?

Comment: @BoltClock: if the answer is the same, why not?

Comment: @Neeku: I don't think it's said in exactly my words, no. Its based on putting a lot of different information from MSO and MSE together.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Just because the answer is the same doesn't always mean the questions are the same. It's very clear that the question here is completely different from any of those linked. If anything it looks like part of the *premise* of this question comes from knowing the answer to those other questions.

Comment: @BoltClock: sure, and here I agree that this one is a separate feature request, although it could be worded a little better as such. But for many cases, if an the answer on duplicate is perfectly suited for a question, then I'd vote to close as such.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Well, maybe I'm just not seeing how it applies to this question.

Comment: @Neeku please don't completely change the meaning of your question which made the current answers invalid. If you have a new question ask a new one instead.

Comment: @BoltClock you should see the revision history. I have rolled back the question to the previous state when the entire concept was completely different. Editing the question so much made my answer with 4 upvotes invalid and therefore 7 people have downvoted it since the edits...unfair, I **don't** think the OP should edit the question so much that it **invalidates current answers**.. New concept should ask new question.

Comment: @Neeku http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265345/the-revision-history-matters - "his advantage" :-)

Answer (score 7):

[let me quote Martijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251320/2140173):

> All sites list all badges even if you cannot earn them, and child
>   metas are no exception. You cannot earn Promoter on a child meta site,
>   but it still is listed **because all badges are listed everywhere.**

Comment: Does this contradict requesting adding this very same information to the badge description?

Comment: @Neeku I think the answer you were looking for is: All badges are listed on all sites; they cannot be retired because of one site only as they can still be awarded on other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd say it's unnecessary to add a small caption to every badge that can't be awarded for whatever reason.

If a user really wants to know why they can't get, for example, the precognitive badge, they'll just [search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&site=webhp&source=hp&q=why+can%27t+i+get+the+precognitive+badge+on+stack+overflow&oq=why+can%27t+i+get+the+precognitive+badge+on+stackover&gs_l=hp.3.0.33i13i21.6059.30966.0.32015.81.63.12.5.5.1.247.6958.0j49j4.53.0....0...1c.1.48.hp..34.47.4295.0.4WTjcpPQaNA); which will just lead them back to the mentioned posts, thus giving them a more than sufficient explanation than,

> This badge cannot be awarded to anyone anymore.