# The revision history matters

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments, revision-history

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/265250/revisions) has been revised so many times and the OP has totally turned things around to his/her advantage.

The original problem/question was:

> Shouldn't "precognitive" badge be marked as "retired" or "not
>   available" somehow? Why is it there?

and since the question has been flagged as a duplicate because [another answer already answered that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251319/what-is-badge-promoter-on-mso-for/251320#251320) the OP started changing the **meaning** of the question.

It invalidated the current answer with 4 upvotes and coming back to the question a few hours later just to find that meanwhile it has received 7 downvotes and the comments indicate that the answer is from another world and does not match the question.

Also [**maybe it's time to improve your searching skills**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=precognitive) has been removed and I have no idea why... It may sound sarcastic but it was completely educative as clicking the link proves to the op that he/she was wrong and didn't search before asking.

[image]

Dear Moderators,

please see the revision history before deleting things and if you see an OP change the meaning of the question please educate or/and rollback.

Comment: As far as educating OP is concerned, it didn't work. I did try to educate this particular user about what kind of edits are acceptable. [I explicitly told](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf#comment54388_262339) "There are multiple posts about what are good edits, and what are bad edits, you can read them and improve your editing.". Maybe if a mod says, it may help.

Comment: Oh, please. You **know** I don't need to look at the revisions to determine that your comment about searching skills is not constructive. And I was not aware of the radical changes to the question until you brought it up, so how do you expect us to roll back something if we haven't seen it yet?

Comment: @BoltClock it's MSO not SO - comments are different here, aren't they? Ok forget the comment, I don't want to argue about it anymore there is no point and it's gone anyway. BUT if you join discussion on a post asked 10+ hours ago with a lot going on with it anyone would expect you, specially being the mod to get familiar with the history of post and see what's is actually going on before deleting things and posting your opinions... You know, you are the papa smurf here and the community expects you to *know best*...

Comment: Hmm, one DV, I wonder who that could be... But yeah, I agree; 5 edits from the OP has altered the post a little too far.

Comment: @mehow, I understand where you're coming from but its unrealistic to ask every reviewer to check the history of every question that hits the queues. If the history of a post has a bearing on how it should be dealt with or is the reason for a flag then that should be explicitly mentioned as a comment to the post.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: It seems to me that you have been weirdly confrontational about the whole thing, and your reaction here is disproportionate to the significance of the referenced post. I guess I'm trying to say: relax man.

Answer (score 18):

> Dear Flaggers,
>
> Please include all relevant information when flagging something for us. If a user has completely changed the question, *tell us that in the flag*.

Flagging is really no different than asking a question: If you want help, you need to share what you know so that we know how to help.

Comment: what does flagging has to do with this!??!

Comment: @mehow: I have read your post a few times and I am having trouble trying to figure out what exactly you are complaining about. I want to support you but I am having trouble figuring out what exactly is going on.