# "Answer posters" alerted when question is edited

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Not sure, but would it make sense to have an alert set up that tells people who have posted answers if the question has been edited?

This post shows how edits can change the question, and there for invalidate answers:
[The revision history matters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265345/the-revision-history-matters?cb=1)

Because of this, can the users who have posted an answer get an alert when the question is edited, so that they can check to see if the edit means they need to change their answer, or would this fill up the "inbox" of people who have posted lots of answers?

Sorry about wording, but not sure how I can make this clear.

Just to clarify, I don't mean to say that this would encourage bigger edits, but some edits change small parts of the question, like describing what the OP has already tried, which could invalidate an answer.

Comment: Why are we making the answer posters the edit mods? Why not somebody else? If an edit invalidates answers, it's invalid and should be rolled back, which is a 2k privilege.

Comment: Edits are not meant to change the nature of questions. 

And in the case of questions not having enough information to begin with, I think it's in StackOverflow's interest to encourage answerers to post comments and use the notification system associated with that (instead of posting tentative incomplete answers).

Comment: @bjb568: Ignoring questions edited by an OP, the suggested edit queue does not show the Answers alongside edited Questions. This suggests to me that any edit be based off its own merits as an improvement or clarification of a question and not how well it may fit with existing answers. Flow/UI is the public face of policy to users so if the site deems the answers irrelevant then why suggest they should always be referenced? If there is specific need for the answers to be taken in to account then a comment saying so should be attached to the flag or below the post for people to see.

Comment: @indivisible It's not hard to tell what is radical change vs acceptable edit without the answers. Changing the meaning of a question is wrong without answers too.

Comment: I like @RetoKoradi's suggestion of it being opt in when you answer a question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Trojan's comment on [my first answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265439/1590950) got me thinking about other non invasive ways to notify the user of Question modifications without using the inbox notification system.

The suggestion of having an opt in/out checkbox for users to decide themselves whether or not to receive notifications on changes as suggested elsewhere in this thread, while a valid direction to go, I think contravenes Stack Exchange's policy of minimising configuration options and setting sane/universally acceptable options on every users' behalf instead of screens and screens of options. The notify toggle just feels like one the over complications that I have seen shot down on those grounds before.

---

I would suggest though that making use of the profile page instead could be a viable way to achieve this without "getting in users' faces" or cluttering up the UI.
I propose that edits to Questions where you have answers get shown similarly to how "unread" reputation changes and new responses are indicated to users -- on your profile page.
As with the other counters of that type, the number and any connected indicators on highlighted rows should get cleared upon viewing the tab.

I have done a quick mock up using the "answers" tab and a coloured textual indication of when the changes happened.
Note the blue "3" beside the second tab "answers".

#### Summary page:

> [image: summary page]

#### Answers tab:

> [image: answers tab]

---

It's a bit crude and perhaps not the best implementation of the more general idea to use the profile page and tab to indicate modifications but hopefully you get the gist.

Instead of the somewhat lengthy `Question was edited ...` text you could use an icon/chevron with a datetime on hover to preserve space or perhaps change the background colour for those list items.

Also the Answers tab isn't the only place I could see it fitting, just the one I selected to prototype with.

Comment: I like this and have changed to answer, as it shows a good way to implement my idea without filling up inbox.

Answer (score 16):

### Edit:

I have come up with what I think is a non invasive solution. I felt it warranted an answer of its own so you can [find it up above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265517/1590950)

---

While I can see the value of such functionality I would be wary of getting behind it. I would see this as spam notifications. It would need to have some very well balanced ways to decide what is and isn't worth pestering a user about.

- Added a tag. PING!
- Corrected a typo. PING!
- Misused a semi-colon; PING!
- Corrected indentation. PING!
- etc
- etc
- etc
- purposeful extra etc
- as there are too many reasons for edits
- that do not change the meaning
- of a post
- bonus etc for the edits that make it through the suggested edit queue that should never have.
- PING! PING! PING! PING! PING! PING!

I only have 160ish answers myself and would not want to get bothered by every modification to a Question that I responded to. I can't imagine what it would be like for somebody who's been active for more than the 6ish months I have.

The wasted energy in vibrations & sounds emitted from somebody like Jon Skeet's phone.  Likely enough wasted energy to run a small country for a week or two.
Maybe Liechtenstein or the Maldives.
Perhaps not large when measured on the conventional country scale but still whole countries!

Comment: +1. I am already bugged by ~2-4 responses on my answers every morning I wake up to check the StackExchange app. Edits are to improve the quality of a post, and shouldn't be major enough to have the answer posters change their answers to cope with the edit. Plus, if you need to notify of answer changes or ask for new issues, leave comments or, outright, post a new question. Also, "bonus etc for the edits that make it through the suggested edit queue that should never have." ;)

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, I had not thought about the many minor changes that are made

Comment: Then alerts (maybe not **all** alerts, but at least for this request) should be bucketed: *Question **"Answer posters" alerted...** updated 3 times since your answer*. Maybe only count since-your-answer-last-updated? This wouldn't solve the problem if you're checking the updates each time you get pinged, though. An opt-in (**and** opt-out) would help there.

Comment: Jon, not John.  Not sure if he cares, but FWIW. :)

Comment: @paqogomez, right you are. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Even ignoring the bigger issue of 'should questions be modified that much', to be remotely acceptable, there would probably need to be two parts to activating such a notification:

1. A positive opt-in by the answerer, roughly like the Community Wiki box that can be marked when creating the answer, that would be inactive by default.
2. A similar check box for the editor to be able to mark the edit as 'substantive', presumably adding new information that was not known when the question was originally asked, or adding code, or something similar.  This too would be inactive by default.

Both of these would be inactive by default.  Both the answerer and the editor would have to explicitly trigger the notification.  There'd also be unnotify mechanism, so that by 'editing' their answer the answerer could turn off notification requests.  If the only change was turning off the notification request, then the answer modification time would not be changed.  The only person who should see whether notifications are sent to them for an answer is the answerer; no-one else needs to see.  There might be a global switch in a user's profile page to 'turn all answer notifications off'.

Some scheme close to this would provide people with sufficient control over such 'question changed' notifications.  It would not be needed often; it can be turned off by the answerer with ease.  And, by default, no-one would be pestered with the information.

Also, this is quite a lot of implementation for a marginal benefit; I'm not convinced it should jump to the top of The Team's feature queue.

Answer (score 2):

If it's opt-in, and some people find it helpful, I wouldn't have a problem with it. I would not want the notifications myself. There's a few kinds of edits, and I don't think I would want a notification for any of them:

1. It's a minor edit. Don't care. The notification is just noise.
2. It's a major edit that fundamentally changes the question and invalidates my answer. Well, to some degree I should know about it. I might be able to roll back the edit, or ask the OP to do that. But to be completely honest, seeing that happen (and it does) makes me mad, and I'm not coming to this site to get upset. So in some way, I would almost prefer to not see it. And yes, I'm aware that the "see no evil" problem solving strategy is not generally a good one.
3. There's a legitimate addition/clarification to the question that allows me to improve my answer. In these cases, the edit was mostly triggered by comments I was involved in, and the OP can notify me with an @name comment. Most of the time I will comment on the question until it is sufficiently clear *before* I write an answer anyway, so this should not happen all that frequently.

In summary, I typically don't need/want to be notified, and in the cases where I do, there's a good mechanism to do that already.

Answer (score 0):

just send it to a review queue, or to just a couple of answers, and ask them to determine whether it is a "substantial edit" or not. also allow the asker to propose that an edit is substantial or minor. the review can be skipped or minimized if asker has high rep.

if deemed substantial, alert all answerers.

and while at it, disallow substantial edits after the question is sufficiently old; suggest asking new question if that be the case.

Comment: That's a fairly substantial reworking of the review and edit workflows. It would take quite a bit of community backing/pressure and discussion. Also, I think the creation of an entirely new queue would be a very hard thing to get implemented. I'm not against the suggestion, just not sure how realistic it would be.