# Do people receive notifications when an answered question is edited?

Tags: support, edits, answers, notifications

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447883/read-out-of-a-csv-file-and-save-it-into-a-sql-lite-in-java) and marked one of the answers as correct.

I then proceeded with the task to get a different problem.

The topic was the same and since I am kind of new here, I tried to delete my post and re-ask the question.

Unfortunately that isn't possible. So I edited it and waited for over a day. Normally people reply very quickly, but **it seems that nobody got notified about my edit?**

My edit was significant. I had only a few sentences at first and now I added other questions and a lot of code.

Comment: Take a look here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265377/answer-posters-alerted-when-question-is-edited

Comment: Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103400/if-i-edit-my-answer-do-commenters-get-notified

Comment: I think if you have a new question, you should post it as a separate question

Comment: You _added other questions_? That doesn't sound right. You may need to familiarize yourself with SO rules.

Comment: That is hard to explain. I was having an issue with the whole thing. I asked for a solution and some people gave me good advice.. However, these answers obviously did not fully answer my question. And as I said, I new here. Thats why i marked one answer as correct, because it helped out alot(wanted to appriciate the guy, because i cant upvote yet.)

Comment: So I was going through a lot of new things and tried my best to solve as much as possible by my own. But when I wasnt able to proceed, i edited the text of my question, by adding my code and where my problem was.

Comment: And to sum it up again... the reason for not posting a new question was, because it would have been marked as a duplicate. :/                                But still, I was actually wondering(thats why I came on *Meta): do the people who where inflicted in my post, still see the edits?

Answer (score 12):

### No, answerers do not get notifications when a question is edited.

That could be very noisy, and very likely to be unproductive.

If the question already has answers; it is safe to assume that **the the answerers had enough information to post an answer**

(Otherwise they should have posted a comment asking for more information/clarification, or voted/flagged to close, etc).

**Bearing that in mind, additional edits to the question shouldn't change things in a way that invalidate already posted answers.**

- If you hadn't posted enough information and the answerers were mostly guessing, well, that's on them for answering unclear questions.
- If you had posted enough information and now you want to change the meaning of the question, **it's on you and you are doing it wrong**.

If you take these things into account, you'll see that the vast majority of edits to an already answered question are simply polishing up the question. (Syntax, format, grammar, etc),  and not changing it in a way where notifying answerers is good or useful, just additional noise to be ignored.

All that being said, if you want to communicate with answerers, you can always post comments to their answers. They will be notified of those. But do try not to be too noisy or chatty.

*(I'm purposely focusing on your explicit question here in meta, and ignoring your question in main your actions there; apparently Tanner is addressing that in their [meta-meta-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365160/1426539))*

Comment: Fine. What I do not really unstand, is why people donwvote a question like mine...? What is wrong with the question?

Comment: @PilotKot Voters might feel it was poorly researched. Also, (and this is something specific to meta), they could be downvoting to express their disagreement with the idea of notifying answerers of edit to questions. But again, voting here wont affect you in any way.

Answer (score 5):

So you asked a question, got an answer you felt happy with, which you marked as the correct answer.

This set of actions is a completed Q&A.

Everything you did after that were incorrect actions in my mind.

Firstly, don't un-accept an answer because you want to ask further questions.

If you have a follow on problem, even if it's related to the previous Q&A, you should never edit a question that you've accepted an answer for.

The only acceptable edit to an answered question is to add some information to your post that could clarify something that would help future users with that specific question.

Your edit was far too drastic and it warranted asking a new question, that you could have linked to your original question for context.

Talking more generally and not getting in to whether your question was good/bad... The only other thing you could have done in hindsight, is not accept the answer when you did. That would have given you an opportunity to add more details to get a more complete answer.

If you want to show appreciation for an answer, you can [up vote it once you have 15 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), you don't have to accept.

Comment: I already refered on the mistake of marking the anser as correct, but thanks for exlaining it in detail.